# Rails and ip-spoofing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, thin, ddos

I have small application on Rails 2.3.2, served with nginx+thin(127).
OS FreeBSD 7.1, DB - Posgresql.

Twise at this week my app has fall.
In log I get something like (~2-50 request per second):

```
/!\ FAILSAFE /!\  Mon Oct 04 20:13:55 +0300 2010
 Status: 500 Internal Server Error
  bad content body
   /usr/home/../../history/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/vendor/rack-1.0/rack/utils.rb:311:in `parse_multipart'
   /usr/home/../../history/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/vendor/rack-1.0/rack/request.rb:125:in `POST'
   /usr/home/../../history/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/request.rb:428:in `request_parameters'
   /usr/home/../../history/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/request.rb:381:in `parameters'
   /usr/home/../../history/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1279:in `assign_shortcuts'
   /usr/home/../../history/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/base.rb:518:in `process_without_filters'
```

Or:

/!\ FAILSAFE /!\  Tue Nov 09 09:24:39 +0200 2010
    Status: 500 Internal Server Error
    IP spoofing attack?!
    HTTP_CLIENT_IP="XX.XX.XX.XX"
    HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR="192.168.XX.XX, YY.YY.YY.YY"

```
/usr/home/../../history/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/request.rb:229:in `remote_ip'
/usr/home/../../history/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1372:in `request_origin'
/usr/home/../../history/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1304:in `log_processing_for_request_id'
/usr/home/../../history/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1296:in `log_processing'
/usr/home/../../history/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/base.rb:522:in `process_without_filters'
```

After that system rests into max open file limit (I guess it open by postgesql sessions), postgresql can't establish new connection and app fall.

Any suggestion, how I can protect my a<del>ss</del>pp in this situation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoted from rails 2.3 release notes :

The fact that Rails checks for IP spoofing can be a nuisance for sites that do heavy traffic with cell phones, because their proxies don’t generally set things up right. If that’s you, you can now set ActionController::Base.ip_spoofing_check = false to disable the check entirely.